# download data daily from website

Tags: unix, centos, unix-timestamp

My download command is like

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer key" "https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/accounts/accounts/sales?break_down=product&start_date=2016-02-01&end_date=2016-02-02"
```

I will have to automate the script to download the data every day. any ideas how do i automate the start date and end date in download link to change daily.

For example start_date=2016-02-01&end_date=2016-02-02" and consequtevely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for this

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

YESTERDAY=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d")

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer key" "https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/accounts/account_id/sales?break_down=product&start_date=$YESTERDAY&end_date=$TODAY" >download.cv
```

This downloads the data for one day. Schedule a cron to run every day at 12.00 am to have the data downloaded every day.